# Running .NET 2.0 4.0 machine without app.config?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am building an application targeted mostly towards Windows 10, but I would also like to include some legacy support for XP+.

I know this is possible by configuring an app.config file with the "startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy" tag.
However I do not want to include a dependency, as that would require me to either A:have an installer that extracts both files or B:have to release the application as an archive.
Both of these options are reasonable, but if at all possible I would like it to be a nice and clean, completely portable, packaged in one executable application.

Speaking of packaged, that leads me to option C. I am aware that I cannot simply add this app.config file as an embedded resource and have the LegacyV2Runtime tag still be active (or maybe I can who knows, I just assumed it would not work). So assuming that's out the window, I previously recall an application that was able to pack all the files Dll's into the executable, and it worked very very well. I do not believe it was ILSpy, as I think it worked with Native code. I am struggling to find this application, but assuming I do find it, would windows possibly recognize the app.config file?

If this does not work, then I guess my next preferred route would be to create an Installer executable. My only languages are .NET and a bit of java, so I'm not sure what language would be ideal to create this in that support XP-Win 10. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: My suggestion would be force the people using XP to cease and desist. They are nothing but virus machines, and they should be upgrading to supported software. I say this in the nicest possible way

Comment: ILMerge can be used to merge DLLs together or into an EXE but that's because they are all assemblies and their IL code can thus be merged.  An app.config file is an XML file so it is something very different.  In order to extract a resource, your app would have to be already running, in which case it's too late.  Why not simply build two versions of your app?  It's not that hard to set a p[roject property or two and select Build from the menu.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the input guys. Just out of curiosity, definitely not going to do this to this program, more so because it is always something I have wanted to attempt, what would one have to do to merge all .NET dll's into the application? I believe you use Mono, but I am not sure what goes into it as I have never really played around with mono before.

Comment: If you exclude the long dead Windows XP/Vista, then .NET Core 3.x enables single file deployment of WinForms/WPF apps, where even .NET Framework is not needed any more.

Comment: @LexLi, just note that there is no .NET Core designer yet for WinForms and I don't think for WPF either.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I don't know from where you got that information. WPF .NET Core designer is fully functional in latest VS2019, while WinForms .NET Core designer is in preview (can cover the simplest cases already).

Comment: @LexLi, I wasn't sure about WPF as I hadn't checked, hence my qualification.  As for WinForms, there's no designer in VS, although the preview can be downloaded separately.  It is just an early preview though, so it's not something anyone should really be using seriously.

Comment: @dogholio, as I said earlier, ILMerge.  I have never used it in anger but I believe that it can be added as a NuGet package and then the merge happens as part of the build.  Don't just blunder into using it without doing some research first though.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Okay, just to clarify I do mean all the needed dlls from the .NET framework into the assembly, not 3rd party dlls. Not sure if ILMerge can do this but I will play around. I have heard of Turbo Studio and Thinstall but not really what I am looking for. Just trying to play around none seem like a practical solution anyways. Thank you all, I have decided to build 2 different versions. Also, new to stack overflow.. How do I mark one of you as answer? Thank you.

Comment: That's not how the. NET Framework works.

Comment: That is what I was under the impression of, yet I have heard of people doing it with Mono and Turbo Studio/Thinstall. I figured we were talking about different things when you recommended ILMerge.